# How to restrict download and print and allow to read the PDF files?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, irm

I have office 365 plan and I want to restrict some of the users to download the files however the user can view the files.
Also, want the same for print. the user can view the document but should not able to print the document.

IRM works well with Office file types,not PDF.Looking for solution for PDF type files.

Comment: As you have not received an answer that works for you, have a look at a 3rd party solution such as http://blog.muhimbi.com/2015/12/add-watermarks-when-files-are-opened-or.html. (It is not just watermarking, it can also apply security settings) Disclaimer, I worked on this so consider me biased, but very knowledgeable on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is Possible for all Office types but sadly not possible for PDF documents .

Supported Types:

- Microsoft Office InfoPath forms
- The 97-2003 file formats for the
  following Microsoft Office programs:  Word, Excel, and PowerPoint
- The Office Open XML Formats for the following Microsoft Office
  programs: Word, Excel, and PowerPoint
- The XML Paper Specification (XPS) format

If its for Office type Documents then, You can do this by enabling Information Rights Management IRM.

> You can use Information Rights Management (IRM) to help control and protect files that are downloaded from lists or libraries.
>
> Microsoft Active Directory Rights Management Services (AD RMS) supports Information Rights Management for sites. No separate or additional installations are required.
>
> To apply IRM to a list or library, you must have administrator permissions for that list or library.
>
> Before you apply IRM to a list or library it must first be enabled by an administrator for your site.

More details steps available at

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-Information-Rights-Management-to-a-list-or-library-3bdb5c4e-94fc-4741-b02f-4e7cc3c54aa1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restrict-permission-to-content-in-a-file-3cdd7eda-79d4-471f-91af-4dd02cc6f764

Comment: I have tried IRM and View Only permission however it is not working with PDF files as IRM encrypt the files so user can not read it and 
using view only permission it shows access denied page.

Comment: sad to know that only below are supported . Microsoft Office InfoPath forms

The 97-2003 file formats for the following Microsoft Office programs: Word, Excel, and PowerPoint

The Office Open XML Formats for the following Microsoft Office programs: Word, Excel, and PowerPoint

The XML Paper Specification (XPS) format

Comment: Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Checking the same

Comment: Still no PDF view only support through RMS